# Where Like (SQL) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

this my code

```
SqlStr = "Select Test From Tbl_Test Where Test ='" & TextBox1 & "'"
```

how add **Like** in **Where** Test and TextBox1 to TextBox1*?

```
SqlStr = "Select Test From Tbl_Test Where Test Like='" & TextBox1* & "'"
```

This code gives an error .

Comment: `SqlStr = "Select Test From Tbl_Test Where Test Like'" & TextBox1 & "%'"`

Comment: tip: debug print your sql string, then try to just run this in access(i assume). access will give you an idea of why your generated string was incorrect...or...try to generate the query you want in Access, then write the VB code to exactly replicate the string needed for your query.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes this is, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the '=' and add appropriate '%'s (which refer to any number of any character) depending on your needs.

The resulting string should be like so:

```
Select Test From Tbl_Test Where Test Like '%yoursearchhere%'
```

e.g.

```
SqlStr = "Select Test From Tbl_Test Where Test Like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

For Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15